# "Error: r is undefined" when using autocomplete in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm building a small app. One of the first steps requires me to make a input box with autocomplete. I'm using Angular Material for that.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>app</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,400italic, 700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

  <body  layout="column" ng-controller="autoCompleteController">
      <h1>Purchase Order</h1>

      <div>
        <div class="row">

        <md-autocomplete flex 
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" 
        md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
        md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.name" 
        placeholder="Product name">
      <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
    </md-autocomplete>
        </div>
      </div>

   <script src="../src/api.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

and JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);


         myApp.controller('autoCompleteController', function($http, $scope) {     
            this.querySearch = function() {
              return $scope.products
                .then(function(result) {
                  $scope.autcomplete =  response.data.name;
                })
            }

$scope.products = [
    {name:"Worn Shortsword",price:3},
    /* 4000 other products inbetween */
    ,{name:"Annealed Blade",price:12980}
];
});
```

I know my code might have some issues and mistakes, since I'm a newbie in Angular, but what bugs me is the error that shows in the console every time I type a letter in the input box:

> Error: r is undefined
> te@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.js:14:2432
> se@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.js:14:3262
> O/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.js:14:16
> e/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:130:409
> vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:103
> vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:142:165
> vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:399
> Pg</this.$$debounceViewValueCommit@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:286:400
> Pg</this.$setViewValue@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:286:128
> lb/l@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:176:478
> Sf@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:37:31
> Rf/d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:36:486

What does it mean? I can't find anything about this error.

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/mEaGrb?editors=1010#0. That .then code in **querySearch** should be removed though.

Comment: Wow, thank you, it stopped throwing that error and almost works. The only problem now is, it only shows the list of products under the input box, but it doesn't actually search the items when you type, you can notice that in your codepen too.

Comment: Instead of returning `$scope.products`, return `$scope.products.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes($scope.searchText))`.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you!